# NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current Win64 channels: - freetype 2.5.5 1

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install a Python Environment using a yml file. However I run into the following error :

```
NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current Win64 channels: 
                      - freetype 2.5.5 1
```

I am using the following code to install the environment using Anaconda 2 (after putting the .yml file in the current directory for Python.)

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

The yml file is as follows taken from the url ( https://github.com/zooniverse/Data-digging/blob/master/example_scripts/basic_project_stats.yml)

```
name: python279_volcrowe
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- cycler=0.10.0=py27_0
- freetype=2.5.5=1
- jpeg=8d=1
- lcms=1.19=0
- libpng=1.6.22=0
- matplotlib=1.5.1=np110py27_0
- numpy=1.10.1=py27_0
- openssl=1.0.2g=0
- pandas=0.17.1=np110py27_0
- pil=1.1.7=py27_2
- pip=8.1.1=py27_0
- pyparsing=2.1.4=py27_0
- pyqt=4.11.4=py27_3
- python=2.7.11=0
- python-dateutil=2.4.2=py27_0
- pytz=2015.7=py27_0
- qt=4.8.7=3
- readline=6.2=2
- requests=2.9.1=py27_0
- setuptools=20.3=py27_0
- sip=4.16.9=py27_0
- six=1.10.0=py27_0
- sqlite=3.9.2=0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py27_0
- zlib=1.2.8=0
prefix: /Users/Public/Anaconda2/envs/python279_volcrowe
```

I was not sure what the last line in the yml file which is 'prefix' is doing, but I changed it to the directory where the environments in my computer reside.

As mentioned in a similar post I tried installing a win 64 channel using:

```
conda config --add channels bioninja
```

I am able to add the bioninja thing but after it when I run the following command:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

It gives me the same Win64 channel error as earlier.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I downloaded the wrong .yml file.
I was working on windows and i run:

> conda env create -f aind-environment-unix.yml

I have downloaded the correct file and run:

> conda env create -f **aind-environment-windows.yml**

and i solved the problem